# Joomla mod_articles_popular and $rowcount

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I want to change the way articles are displayed with Articles - Most Read Module. I want them to show on 3 columns, but iam stack at $rowcount.

```
<div class="cols-3 row-fluid clearfix">
 <?php foreach ($list as $item) : ?>
  <div class="span4">
  <div class="column- .....
    <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>">
    <?php echo $item->title; ?></a>
  </div>
  </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

I would try something like this:

```
<div class="item column-<?php echo $rowcount; ?>
```

But i don't know how to define rowcount...

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code to.

```
<div class="cols-3 row-fluid clearfix">
 <?php foreach ($list as $i => $item) : ?>
  <div class="span4">
  <div class="column-<?php echo $i % 3 + 1; ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>">
    <?php echo $item->title; ?></a>
  </div>
  </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Reference: [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)